# IE8 + IE9 HTML and CSS Focus

Tags: html, css, input, focus, border

I'm working on an HTML page where we would like the `input` fields and `select` dropboxes to have a border around it as it is tabbed through and in focus. I've defined an input class within my CSS like so:

```
input.highlight:focus {
border: #003366;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;    
}
```

The input field is defined within my HTML file like so:

```
<input class="highlight" name="attorneyName" id="attorneyName" type="text" value="John Jackson" size="50" maxlength="30">
```

The focus seems to work fine in Chrome, but in IE the focus remains on one of my buttons no matter what I do. The button seems to steal the focus attribute and the page never focuses on any input fields, so the fields are never shown with a border around them while they are being tabbed through. What might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you throw up a jsFiddle or share the full code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/raphnguyen/7Btj3/. It seems to focus properly in jsFiddle as well, but not on my IE8 or IE9 builds.

Comment: In that case do you have a live link we can check as it is probably something other than the CSS/HTML you have given us.

Comment: Works fine for me. It’s something else on your page, perhaps in JavaScript code, perhaps in CSS rules that override the one you showed.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't as these are mockups and not yet implemented into the system. This seems strange to me as Slate.css is the only CSS being referenced from the HTML.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the !DOCTYPE?

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to work just fine in IE8. Can't test IE9 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another thread, someone was able to point out that the `:focus` attribute is only recognized in IE9. This explains why the jsFiddle version works properly. When running the HTML file from my local drive, however, IE9 runs in compatibility mode for IE8 and lower and the `:focus` attribute is never recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the tab index attribute to the page elements. This property is supported by all major browsers. Supporting Browsers are : IE, safari,firefox,chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This correctly tabs to the field that I set as `tabindex="1"`, but does not fix the focus problem. Setting `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` makes the page focus properly, but I lose other elements of the page. Is there a DOCTYPE that might fix my problem while maintaining compatibility with the other elements of my page?

Comment: @raphnguyen: If you aren't using a doctype, you can't be helped.

Answer (score 0):

**" The button seems to steal the focus attribute and the page never focuses on any input fields, so the fields are never shown with a border around them while they are being tabbed through."**

If i understand your question clearly then you have an issue while tabbing from one element to another right?.

If that is the case the tab-index with increasing index value(or any order) will let you to select next elements while tabbing based on the tab-index set up, and the DOCTYPE Tag specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly. Of course the changes in the Doctype tends to changes in the page. Have a quick look on w3 schools about doctype, Hope it may spot some light.

Cheers,
Arun

Comment: No, I do not have trouble tabbing from one element to another. I have set a focus attribute to each text field so that when it is in focus, a user can see this visually with a border around it. What happens instead is no matter what field the user is on, the only thing that inherits the focus attribute is the `Jail Address` button. Text fields can be tabbed through and edited just fine, but will never indicate that it is in focus with a visual border.

Comment: Can you share your code , so that i do work on it and hope to help you